# Is a url-encoded string html-safe (no injection possibilities)?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, urlencode

Let's say I have the following code on my view page (in asp.net mvc 3 razor):

```
<a href='https://example.com/search?q=@Url.Encode(Model.UserInput)'>Click here</a>
```

`Model.UserInput` is a user input string that could contain any characters.

Is this totally safe, in terms of html injection and cross site scripting?  Or should I HTML encode the query string after URL encoding it as well?

Of course, usually I'd eliminate dangerous input before this stage, but that's not the point.

Comment: Url encoding and HTML encoding are very different things.

Comment: @Oded Yes, of course - I guess I should have been clearer.  What I'm wondering is: Do I also need to html encode it?

Comment: If you want to be completely safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this totally safe

Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. I would approach this problem with another angle, ignoring safety just for now...

URL encoding serves a purpose: [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (what it's actual name is) a url. Imagine "url encoding" would replace all spaces with `<space width='1'>` instead of the actual `%20` or whatever the heck it does now.  The url "`...?q=foo bar`" would become, in our imaginary example, "`...?q=foo<space width='1'>bar`" and be a correctly "url encoded" url. This might be useful in a PDF or CSV file or whatever other type of output you'd be creating, but in HTML this would cause trouble. In your case because of the `'` which would "end" the `href` attribute leaving `1'>` as garbage.

```
<a href='https://example.com/search?q=foo<space width='1'>'>
```

Because your output is intended for HTML you should actually, IMHO at least, do `HTMLEncode(URLEncode(MyUrl))` (pseudocode).

Remember this: **escaping is always done within a specific context**. For SQL you need some "mysql_real_escape"-alike stuff to escape quotes etc. to avoid SQL injection vulnarabilities. In HTML you need to escape characters like `"` and `<`, in an RTF file you would need to escape even other strings/characters like (I don't actually know) `\` would become `\\` or something similar, in a CSV file you'd need to escape `,` or `;` within a field value and in a JSON output you'd need a string containing a `"` to be escaped as `\"`. Each type of output(format) needs it's own escaping/encoding.

What you are now doing is "nesting contexts", you're nesting a "url context" in an "HTML context". So you'd have to escape/encode accordingly.

[As TrueBlue demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550897/215042) it is not safe.

Answer (score 3):

You *must* URL encode query string parameters; you cannot and should not pass them in their raw form. The parameters (the user input in your case) could contain special URI characters such as `?`, `=` and `&`. Without encoding, the user input `hansel&gretel` becomes `https://example.com/search?q=hansel&gretel`; the `q` query string parameter only contains `hansel`.

In addition, you must *HTML encode any HTML*; even those fragments that are used inside attrbute values. This is to make sure that if any character that has special meaning in HTML such as `<`, `>` and `&` get converted to their respective HTML entities. Url encoding eliminates most of these cases but you should still make this a habit.

Note that `'` by-passes URL encoding!! and it will (I think) also by pass HTML encoding too. Don't use `'` as a HTML attribute delimiter or make sure that your HTML encoding function converts `'` to `&#039;` or `&apos;`.